# asp.net mvc login form in layout page (The partial view 'LogIn' was not found)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In Asp.net MVC I have a login form on top of all pages (in _Layout page) and I put my login form in a PartialView as _Login in **Shared Folder** like this:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.LogInModel
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">Login</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogIn", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "login" }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input-block-level", placeholder = "username" })    
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)    

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input-block-level", placeholder = "password" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

        <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" class="btn btn-primary" />

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
    }
</div>
```

and in my _Layout page:

```
<a id="popover" href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">Login</a>    
 <div id="login">
    @Html.Partial("_LogIn")                     
 </div>
```

and AccountController contains:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(LogInModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }                    

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "login failed");
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

When ModelState is not valid I get this error in browser:

> The partial view 'LogIn' was not found or no view engine supports the
>   searched locations

What is the problem with Controller? How can I return just _Login partialview in _Layout page on this line? :

```
return PartialView(model);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for returning a partial view you need to specify the partial view name.  on your view you have the partial as _LogIn but on your controller you leave it as the default so it is looking for Login.  Try changing your controller to

```
return PartialView("_LogIn", model);
```

Comment: do you have unobtrusive-ajax referenced on your page?

Comment: Yes, I refenece it and in it is added in bundles too!

Comment: I haven't used ajax.beginform before so not entirely sure.  I always use an ajax call in the javascript.  Just guessing you might try changing 'login' to '#login'.  if that doesn't work look at the source on your page and see where it is being put and hopefully you will see something there that will help

Comment: In Index when I hit the submit, it goes to /Account/LogIn and takes full of the page wtih my partial view!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773706/mvc4-ajax-form-in-partial-view-returns-whole-page-when-inside-kendo-window here is a question that looks similar to what you are experiencing.  hopefully something here will help

Answer (score 1):

u must name your partial view as ur method

```
@Html.Partial(_login)
```

and at the Controller

```
public ActionResult _login(...)
{
....
return PartialView(model);
}
```

or you can name them differently but ur Controller will be like that

```
public ActionResult Login(...)
{
... 
return PartialView("_login",model);
}
```

Comment: Not entirely true. If the name of the view is not supplied in the call, then the Razor engine will default to using the method name. However you can easily return any view you want by using the override that takes the view's name as it's first argument. Check @MattBodily's answer for correct use.

Comment: Thanks it works but my partial view takes full of page although I write: UpdateTargetId = "login", why?

Comment: did u tried `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` ??? and also check ur tags , u may have `<div>` not closed

Answer (score 1):

Because my _Layout page just has a model and I want to redirect to same page if form requires validation, so I used this line in my Controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

instead of returning PartialView as `return PartialView("_LogIn", model);`

thanks to all.